Parse json from Google trend api
I used this Google trend url to get information Google Trend, but the format of response can not parse to json"
https://trends.google.com/trends/api/dailytrends?hl=en-US&tz=-420&geo=US&hl=en-US&ns=15
Is there a way to process the response into json?
I tried to change the response, but look like not right.
